# Exclude certain string bash

Tags: bash, shell

```
echo "How many days old are the branches you want to delete"
echo -n "[Branches age]: "
read userDays
echo "Deleting branchs older than $userDays day old:"
sudo find $FOCUS_HOME -maxdepth 1 -mtime +$userDays -printf '%f\n' -exec rm -rf {} \
echo "Done! All branchs $userDays days old are removed"
```

I have this simple script shown above that will delete my branches that are kept on my computer after whatever days I put in, that will look at my last time I modified that branch, avoiding me from deleting a branch I might have recently been working on even though its old. I wanted to add an exlusion to this. Basically this will usually return something like:

```
austins-123456
```

and then launch an rm -rf on that folder. But I want to have it exclude a certain string:

```
trunk
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe :

```
sudo find $FOCUS_HOME -maxdepth 1 -mtime +$userDays ! -name 'trunk' -printf '- %f\n' -exec rm -rf {} \
```

? :)

Check the `-path` switch too.

If it's for `git` or `svn`, maybe there's a more proper solution

Comment: Looks like that worked however.


sudo find $FOCUS_HOME -maxdepth 1 -mtime +$userDays ! -name 'trunk' -printf '%f\n' -exec rm -rf {} \

Otherwise you get:
find: warning: you have specified the -maxdepth option after a non-option argument !, but options are not positional (-maxdepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments.

Comment: How would I actually add more than 1 string, Say I wanted to avoid trunk, austins-123, austins-321. Also its SVN however I dont want to actually remove the svn path or anything just from my local computer I want it to stay in the repo just not taking space on my computer.. lol

Comment: Check -a and -o switchs from the man page. Maybe need parenthesis regroupment